# In SAS EG4 i have to find Top 10 customer name within top 10 country name by region

Tags: group-by, sas, sas-macro

below is the sample data

`Data read; input region$ Country$ Customername$ Amount; dataline; asia china xx 78 asia pak xx 89 africa tunisia  xx  contd ; run;`
I want top 10 customer of top 10 country by region. Can anyone guide or help

i tried Proc tabulate and proc means but not giving results. I cannot show the result as it is office laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show the `Proc MEANS` code you tried.

Try using Proc MEANS with some follow up SORT and DATA steps to get the results you want.

Example:

```
data have;
  call streaminit(20230417);

  do region = 1 to 20;
    do customer = 1 to 100+rand('integer', 25);
      customerId + 1;
      amount = rand('integer', 1, 2500);
      output;
    end;
  end;
  keep region customerid amount;
run;

proc means noprint data=have;
  class region customerId;
  var amount;
  types region region*customerId;
  output out=summary sum=totalamount;
run;

proc sort data=summary;
  by region descending totalamount;

data top10region;
  set summary;
  where _type_ = 2;
  if _n_ > 10 then stop;
run;

data top10c_in_top10r;
  merge top10region(rename=totalamount=regiontotal) summary(where=(_type_=3));
  by region;

  if first.region then regionCount + 1;
  if regionCount > 10 then stop;

  if first.region 
    then counter = 1;
    else counter + 1;

  if counter <= 10 then output;

  keep region customerId regionTotal regionTotal totalAmount;
  rename totalAmount=customerTotal;
run;
```

[image]